# Check if element exists SetInterval in For Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm trying to check if each element has been populated before generated a gauge. The gauge value is being set by another API so having to wait for the value to be present.

Having the check in the For Loop doesn't seem to work

```
function refreshGauge() {
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
var targetTDs = table.querySelectorAll(".myfindclass2");
for (var i = 0; i < targetTDs.length; i++) {
  var td = targetTDs[i];
  var fvals = td.querySelectorAll("[id*='calcValue']");
  var fval = fvals[0].innerText.replace('%','');
  var checkElem = "#" + fvals[0].getAttribute('id');
  console.log(checkElem)
//HERE Doesn't work 

var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if ($(checkElem).length) {
      console.log("Exists!");
         nextstep(td)
      clearInterval(checkExist);
  }
}, 100); // check every 100ms   


  }
 console.log('done')
} ;


    refreshGauge()
```

The above results in an infinite loop checking the element only a single element.

**If I use the below it works but I don't to list all 36+ in the list :**

What is the best way to accomplish having each element checked to ensure the values populated before creating/updating the gauge.

```
function refreshGauge() {
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
var targetTDs = table.querySelectorAll(".myfindclass2");
for (var i = 0; i < targetTDs.length; i++) {
  var td = targetTDs[i];
  var fvals = td.querySelectorAll("[id*='calcValue']");
  var fval = fvals[0].innerText.replace('%','');
  var checkElem = "#" + fvals[0].getAttribute('id');
  console.log(checkElem)


nextstep(td)


  }
 console.log('done')
} ;  

  var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
     if ($('gauge1').length && $('gauge2').length && $('gauge3').length  && $('gauge4').length) {
        console.log("Exists!");
         refreshGauge()
        clearInterval(checkExist);
    }
  }, 100); // check every 100ms
```

After testing the two codes I learned I should be evaluating the if the value I need is still undefined or has a value.  `var fval = fvals[0].innerText.replace('%','');`

I'm trying something like this but not working :

```
function refreshGauge() {
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
var targetTDs = table.querySelectorAll(".myfindclass2");
for (var i = 0; i < targetTDs.length; i++) {
  var td = targetTDs[i];
  var fvals = td.querySelectorAll("[id*='calcValue']");
  var fval = fvals[0].innerText.replace('%','');
  var checkElem = "#" + fvals[0].getAttribute('id');
  console.log(fval )
//HERE Doesn't work 

var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if (fval.length) {
      console.log("Exists!");
         nextstep(td)
      clearInterval(checkExist);
  }
}, 100); // check every 100ms   


  }
 console.log('done')
} ;


    refreshGauge()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like extracting a `waitForElement` function which takes an element selector as an argument and returns a promise resolving the found element might be quite helpful.

You can loop through the tds, get the selector id and pass it to the `waitForElement` function and `.then` `nextstep`

```js
function refreshGauge() {
    const table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
    const targetTDs = table.querySelectorAll(".myfindclass2");
    targetTDs.forEach(td => {
        const td = targetTDs[i];
        const fvals = td.querySelectorAll("[id*='calcValue']");
        const selector = "#" + fvals[0].getAttribute("id");
        waitForElement(selector)
            .then(() => nextstep(td))
    })
}
function waitForElement(selector) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const checkExist = setInterval(function () {
            const elements = $(selector)
            if (elements.length) {
                clearInterval(checkExist);
                resolve(elements[0]);
            }
        }, 100);
    })
}
```

**Note arrow functions, const and Promise usage might not be acceptable in all browsers**

Comment: thank you, I'll give this a shot, I'll have to make some changes as I'm using this cross browsers and internet explorer doesn't accept =>

Comment: Definitely. Also, note Promise support https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

Comment: I actually believe there is an issue with the `.then` after the `waitForElement` as `nextstep` needs to perform work with reference to the td and not the "found element".. making an adjustment now.